# Laurent series $f(z)=\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, laurent-series

I came across to calculate an integral for which I had to find the Laurent series of $f(z)=\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{z+i}$.

I see that at $z=-i$ the function has a simple pole and the Laurent series I got is as follows:

for $0<|z|<1$ we have $\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{i}\,\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{z}{i}} \right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{i}\,\left(1-\dfrac{z}{i}+\dfrac{z^2}{i^2}-\cdots \right)$

and for $|z|>1$ we have $\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{z}\,\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{i}{z}} \right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{z}\,\left(1-\dfrac{i}{z}+\dfrac{i^2}{z^2}-\cdots \right)$.

Thus $f(z)=\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{i}\,\left(1-\dfrac{z}{i}+\dfrac{z^2}{i^2}-\cdots \right)+\dfrac{\sqrt{z}}{z}\,\left(1-\dfrac{i}{z}+\dfrac{i^2}{z^2}-\cdots \right)$.

I am not particularly sure about the answer. Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no continuous branch of $\sqrt z$ in a neighborhood of $0$ so the question does not make sense. Besides you cannot have $\sqrt z$ in the terms of any Laurent series.

Comment: Oh yeah! I get it. Thank you Sir @Kavi Rama Murthy